# How to do the "Action segue modal" in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I am using Xcode 4.6 with storyboards.

In my storyboard I have a couple of `UIViewControllers` and with a button click I want to go from on `ViewController` to another. 
I have done this via adding a "Round Rect Button", control clicking it and dragging it to the `ViewController` I want to go to when the button is clicked and selected the "Action segue: modal".

This works perfectly fine! But I need to be able to do the same thing in code.

Thanks in advance for replies!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dragging from button to destination VC, you make a new segue modal by `Ctrl-dragging` from source VC to destination VC, name the identifier.
In your code, assume that you have an `UIButton` named `mybtn`. You can do the following step:

in *viewDidLoad*

```
[mybtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in *btnclicked* method:

```
- (void)btnclicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your_segue_identifier_name" sender:self];
}
```

finally, you can setup your data if you want to pass object between VC using the following delegate method. If you just simple navigate to destination VC, you could omit it:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"your_segue_identifier_name"]) {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```